# How do I use Pytorch models in Deep Java Library(DJL)?

Tags: python, java, nlp, pytorch, djl

I would like to run [EasyNMT](https://github.com/UKPLab/EasyNMT) in Java.
However I don't know how to load and run the model.

I loaded the model as follows:

```
URI uri = new URI("file:////Users/.../prior.pth");
Path modelDir = Paths.get(uri);
Model model = Model.newInstance("model.pth", Device.cpu(), "PyTorch");
model.load(modelDir);
```

However, I do not know what to do after this.
EasyNMT performs the following:

```
model.translate("Dies ist ein Satz in Deutsch.", target_lang='en', max_new_tokens=1000)
```

How does DJL perform translations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create your own `Translator` to do pre-processing and post-processing. You can find [this jupyter notebook](https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/jupyter/pytorch/load_your_own_pytorch_bert.ipynb) that explains how `Translator` works in DJL.

For NMT model, you can find this example in DJL: https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl/blob/master/examples/docs/neural_machine_translation.md

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I see that I can't use it directly.
I'll take a look at the documentation once!